# How do I create an entity with a map of a list of entities in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Book entity

```
@Entity @Table(name="book")
public class BookModel {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    // other variables Constructors, setters and getters
}
```

An author model with many to many rel with the BookModel

```
@Entity @Table(name="author")
public class AuthorModel {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    // other variables Constructors, setters and getters
}
```

Now I want to create a CatalogueModel that has a map of authors, genres with their different list of books, like so

```
@Entity @Table(name="catalogue")
public class CatalogueModel {
    @Id private Long id;

    private Map<String,  ArrayList<BookModel>>

    private Map<AnEnumOfGenre, ArrayList<BookModel>>
    // other variables Constructors, setters and getters
```

How do I implement this in Spring boot?

Comment: First, `private Map<String,  ArrayList<BookModel>>` the `key` of this map should be `AuthorModel`, shouldn't it? 
Secondly, what do you mean by `implement this in Spring boot`? Could you please explain what you intend to accomplish?

Comment: The key of ```private Map<String,  ArrayList<BookModel>>``` should be String, the name of the author, the value should be the list of the author's books. Implement, I mean how do I write the code. I want to map a list of books to a particular author's name. Thanks. @yoni